Running a Jupyter notebook from a folder in Colab
I was trying to run a notebook from a folder in Colab. It imports other python files, so I used sys.path.append('/content/drive/MyDrive/[my folder]'). It successfully imports some files. However, one of the files in this folder failed to access other files （the csv file in the screenshot). How to resolve this issue?
enter image description here

You aren't specifying the path correctly it looks like but it is hard to tell because you don't include the actual full error. That's a no-no on Stackoverflow. See under 'Help others reproduce the problem' in How do I ask a good question? where it emphasizes to include the error message and code as text. Anyway, once you import it, it is using the path relative to the notebook so put the CSV in with the notebook or specify the path better.

When you load price_df with pd.read_csv, instead of "price_data.csv", try using the full path "/contents/...csv"
